# What is the need of employee emp in the given code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I m trying to understand the given code , Could someone please tell me what exactly **employee emp** is doing here?
Here is the code:-

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
   Employee emp;
   string cnstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abcd123"].ConnectionString;
   try
   {
       using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(cnstr))
       {
           string query = @"
            select
                 ID , FULL_NAME  ,EMAIL_ADDRESS , CURR_DIVISION , CURR_DEPARTMENT
            from
                 T_EMPLOYEE
            where
                 ID = :ID";

           emp = connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Employee>(query, new { ID = id });
       }
       return View(emp);
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw;
   }

}
```

Comment: please read about [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so that next time you can do it correctly.

Comment: Is the question why it is defined at the beginning of method and not where value is assigned? Can you clarify what exactly you don't know?

Comment: The question is not about whether its defined in beginning or not , it was about what role employee emp has in the given code

Answer (score 4):

`Employee emp;` is the declaration of the local variable `emp` of type `Employee`. No value is assigned at this point.

`Employee` is a class holding the properties of an employee like id, name, and date of birth. The O/R-mapper (EF or EF Core) automatically converts the records of the database into objects of this type.

Optionally the variable could be declared and initialized at the same place. The line `Employee emp;` must then be dropped and instead the query would look like this:

```
Employee emp = connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Employee>(query, new { ID = id });
return View(emp);
```

The return statement must then be moved inside the `using` statement, because the scope of `emp` is now limited to the using block.

Alternatively, since now the compiler can infer the type from the initialization code (the code to the right of the `=`), you can use `var`:

```
var emp = connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Employee>(query, new { ID = id });
return View(emp);
```

Note that `emp` is still strongly typed as `Employee`. Just that we let the compiler find this out instead of writing it down explicitly.

or you can drop the temporary variable altogether:

```
return View(connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Employee>(query, new { ID = id }));
```

Note that the `using` statement is still doing its job of closing and disposing the connection before the method returns. This is the magic of C#.

Comment: So basically emp is an instance of model employee, right? And what exactly the difference between an instance and an object?

Comment: A class is a blueprint, a definition. An object is an instance of this class. See [Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes).

Answer (score 1):

Employee is the `Model` of your `View`. It gets filled in `emp` instance by calling:
`connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Employee>(query, new { ID = id });`

And it is returned in the view by:

```
return View(emp);
```

Comment: I m confusing between instance and object

Answer (score 0):

Employee emp is initially not assigned any value.

When data is returned from Oracle database based on Id the value gets stored in emp.

Now, this emp is also the View Model for  your controller method. The data returned from emp is pushed to View.

You must be having this value accessible from View file by using
@model Employee

@Model.[property Name]